# How to mask groupby dataframe by identity matrix

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to mask the dataframe that had groupby index by identity matrix.

#### Dataframe:

```py
s = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
df = DataFrame([{'B1': '1A', 'B2': '', 'B3': '', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': '', 'U_B3': ''},
                {'B1': '3A', 'B2': '1A', 'B3': '', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': 'A', 'U_B3': ''},
                {'B1': '3A', 'B2': '1A', 'B3': '', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': 'A', 'U_B3': ''},
                {'B1': '41A', 'B2': '28A', 'B3': '3A', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': 'A', 'U_B3': 'A'},
                {'B1': '41A', 'B2': '28A', 'B3': '3A', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': 'A', 'U_B3': 'A'},
                {'B1': '41A', 'B2': '28A', 'B3': '3A', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': 'A', 'U_B3': 'A'}])

df.set_index(s)

    B1   B2   B3 U_B1 U_B2 U_B3
0   1A             A        
1   3A   1A        A    A   
1   3A   1A        A    A   
2   41A  28A  3A   A    A   A
2   41A  28A  3A   A    A   A
2   41A  28A  3A   A    A   A
```

#### Target:

```
    B1   B2   B3 U_B1 U_B2 U_B3
0   1A             A        
1   3A   1A        A        
1   3A   1A             A   
2   41A  28A  3A   A   
2   41A  28A  3A        A   
2   41A  28A  3A            A
```

And as the code below, now seems I've some problem about to drop the ' ' value in the group.

```
df[['U_B1','U_B2','U_B3']] = df.groupby(df1.index)['U_B1','U_B2','U_B3'].apply(lambda x: x.drop(x == '')).mask(np.identity(len(x))==0)
```

and got error:
`ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

How can I deal with it?

And if there's other methods also can reach the target.

---

### Question update:

#### Dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame([{'B1': '1A', 'B2': '', 'B3': '', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': '', 'U_B3': ''},
                {'B1': '3A', 'B2': '1A', 'B3': '', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': 'A', 'U_B3': ''},
                {'B1': '41A', 'B2': '28A', 'B3': '3A', 'U_B1': 'A', 'U_B2': 'A', 'U_B3': 'A'}])

# Duplicate rows 
val = (df[['U_B1','U_B2','U_B3']] != '').sum(axis=1)
df1 = df.loc[np.repeat(val.index,val)]  
df1.index.names = ['index']
df1

    B1   B2   B3  U_B1  U_B2  U_B3
index                       
0   1A             A        
1   3A    1A       A     A  
1   3A    1A       A     A  
2   41A  28A  3A   A     A     A
2   41A  28A  3A   A     A     A
2   41A  28A  3A   A     A     A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca use custom function with filtered columns by length for same size by mask, filter by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and add removed columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) per groups:

```
df1 = df.set_index(s)

def f(x):
    a = x.iloc[:, :len(x)]
    m = np.identity(len(x)).astype(bool)
    return a.where(m,'').reindex(x.columns, axis=1, fill_value='')

df1[['U_B1','U_B2','U_B3']] = (df1.groupby(df1.index)['U_B1','U_B2','U_B3'].apply(f)
                                  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df1)
    B1   B2  B3 U_B1 U_B2 U_B3
0   1A             A          
1   3A   1A        A          
1   3A   1A             A     
2  41A  28A  3A    A          
2  41A  28A  3A         A     
2  41A  28A  3A              A
```

Comment: An another additional question. I apply this func. to the dataframe part of my code which have "index" level name on the index column. And got `ValueError: Duplicated level name: "index", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0.`. Is there need to do some trans. for the index column first in this case? Thanks

Comment: @xiumpt - Is possible change data for see this problem?

Comment: @xiumpt so you need last `df1 = df1.reset_index()` ? If not, my solution working in pandas 0.24.2 nice.

Comment: sorry, after checked, the line `df1 = df1.reset_index()` isn't needed. But my df is must with the level name `index`. It works well without `df1.index.names = ['index']`, but will got error with it.

Comment: @xiumpt - What is your pandas version?

Comment: my pandas version is 0.24.2 too

Comment: @xiumpt - I test it under win7, python 3.5. Possilbe solution is create column from index by `df = df.reset_index()`, apply solution with change `df.index` to `'index'` and last set index - `df = df.set_index('index')`